# Telerik ajax manager causes validation of wrong block

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic, telerik, telerik-ajax

I've got page where datagrid is used. The problem is that this datagrid is something like dynamyc builded. I mean if I pass param = 1, then my page filled with grid of 3 columns, that contains some data and can be edited, deleted and added. If I pass param = 2 it filles the same datagrid from the same source, but takes from db more data.

Here is some code:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ViewGroupRecords.ascx.cs" Inherits="Fuse8.Internal.DomainAudit.Web.Modules.Manage.ViewGroupRecords" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Fuse8.Internal.DomainAudit.Domain" %>

<telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="ramDataGrid" runat="server">
    <AjaxSettings>
        <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="dtgRecordsGrid">
            <UpdatedControls>
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="dtgRecordsGrid" LoadingPanelID="raLoadingPanel">
                </telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl>
            </UpdatedControls>
        </telerik:AjaxSetting>
    </AjaxSettings>
</telerik:RadAjaxManager>
<telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel ID="raLoadingPanel" runat="server">        </telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel>
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
<table class="noborder">
<tr>
    <td>Client :</td>
    <td><%=ClientName %></td>
</tr>
</table>
</asp:PlaceHolder>
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="pnlViewClient" runat="server">
    <table class="noborder">
<tr>
         <td>Group :</td>
     <td><%=GroupName %></td>
</tr>
</table>

<ul class="view-all-dem">
<li><a href="ViewDomains.aspx?ShowMode=ByGroup">View Domains</a></li>
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptRecordTypes">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li>&nbsp;|&nbsp;
            <%#IsCurrentRecord(Container.DataItem as RecordType, "<span class='grey'>", "<a href='" +GetUrlToRecord(Container.DataItem as RecordType) + "'>")%>
            <%# ((RecordType)Container.DataItem).Name%> records
            <%#IsCurrentRecord(Container.DataItem as RecordType, "      </span>", "</a>")%>             
        </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
</ul>
<br class="clearall" />
</asp:PlaceHolder>

<asp:datagrid id="dtgRecordsGrid" CssClass="grid" AutoGenerateColumns="false" BackColor="#000" Cellpadding="0" Cellspacing="0" runat="server" AlternatingItemStyle-BackColor="#F7F5F1" DataKeyField="Id">
<ItemStyle BackColor="White"></ItemStyle>
<HeaderStyle CssClass="dtgHeader"></HeaderStyle>
<EditItemStyle CssClass="editing"></EditItemStyle>
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="ID" DataField="Id" ItemStyle-Width="30" ReadOnly="True"></asp:BoundColumn> 

    <asp:EditCommandColumn HeaderText="Edit" EditText="Edit" ItemStyle-CssClass="edit" CancelText="Cancel" HeaderStyle-CssClass="center" UpdateText="OK" ButtonType="LinkButton" />
    <asp:ButtonColumn ItemStyle-CssClass="dtgCell delete" CommandName="Delete" HeaderText="Delete" Text="Delete" HeaderStyle-CssClass="center" ItemStyle-Width="50" />      
</Columns>
</asp:datagrid>

<asp:PlaceHolder ID="pnlAddValue" runat="server">
<asp:button id="btnAdd" CssClass="btn120 domain-finder" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundPosition='0px -25px'" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundPosition='0px 0px'" runat="server" Text="Add Record >"/>
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

As you can see it is just datagrid and some placeholders, **But** there are some code behind that adds columns to datagrid, and some inputs to `pnlAddValue`.

The probles is: there are validators on some fields when using editcommandcolumn and some validators on fields in `pnlAddValue` section.
As you can understand all validators are added dynamically.
When I click "OK" while editing, it causes validation on fields that in add section, ton in edit.

Can you show where is the mistake, or is there some property I need to use in ajax manager?

Comment: are you using validation groups in the validators?

Comment: @bodee, no it is just validators on each textbox.

Comment: I believe you have to work with validation groups. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227424%28v=vs.100%29.aspx